# "many particle system" or "many particles system"

Tags: grammatical-number

In Physics it is common to refer to a "many particle system". Should we not say "many particles system"?

Comment: Answered in [“woman” or “women” as a stand-in for the adjective “female”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161590/woman-or-women-as-a-stand-in-for-the-adjective-female). There's resistance, especially in the US, to the use of plural nouns attributively. Though in some cases (women doctors, sports centre, dogs home) the alternative seems less acceptable.

Comment: Consider: *A system of many particles*

Comment: FWIW, I would use *many-particle system*, not *many particle system*.

Answer (score 5):

Particle here is acting as an adjective for the word **system**, so the plural doesn't need to be applied to it.

Just as in

- Two Car Garage
- Two Income Household
- Five Year Plan
- Hundred Year Flood
- Three Body Problem

Answer (score 0):

To minimize the possibility of confusion on the part of the reader, I would suggest using *multi* rather than *many* and using a hyphen and using the singlar:

*"We are dealing with a multi-particle system."*