# Member's Price or Members Price or Member Price

Tags: grammatical-number, possessives

I have a members only website. I want to place a price tag for "Members Price" is that correct or Member Price. It refers to the price a member pays.

Comment: Or *"Members' Price".*

Comment: Have a look at use of plural forms of nouns used attributively in [this thread](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161590/woman-or-women-as-a-stand-in-for-the-adjective-female/161619#161619), and at dropping apostrophes for associative rather than true possessive constructions in [this thread](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134886/st-matthews-vs-st-matthew/134897#134897).

Comment: _Members’ Price_ would be my choice: it’s the price that members pay, so it’s ‘their’ price (somewhere between associative and truly possessive). But you can also use the plain noun as a noun adjunct, and you can refer to either each individual member or all the members as one—so basically, all four can be used.

Comment: I would use "Member Price" or "Member's Price".  Definitely not "Members Price".

Answer (score -1):

Stick with "members price" (attributive) or "members' price" (possessive) to indicate all members. Don't use "member" or "member's."