# Using two plurals in a row

Tags: grammatical-number

I have been wondering, how would I state this:

"Loading Bitmaps Settings"

It seems weird if either of them were singular, but it looks weird the way it is.

A second example:

"It roots plants"

"It favors pears"

Also, actually are a bit different...

"who steals products that are broken"

Comment: Answered at ["woman" or "women" as a stand-in for the adjective "female"?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/161590/woman-or-women-as-a-stand-in-for-the-adjective-female)

Answer (score 3):

Without any more context I'd say it should be "Loading Bitmap Settings". In this case the settings apply to all bitmaps.

Comment: Yes that is right, I don't know why it didn't sound right before. Thanks.

Comment: I added a few more examples in different formats...

Comment: @Evan Carslake, look at anything long enough and it starts looking odd. Nice to know it helped.

Comment: The second example shows three verbs and looks good to me.